# How do I blend two textures with different co-ordinates in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I can blend two textures with different blending modes in the fragment shader when both the textures covers the same rectangles. But now my problem is, one texture is a plain rectangle with no rotation and the other texture is another rectangle with a rotation/scale and translation. How do I merge these textures in the way I want? (In the picture)

I know how to do this...

[image]

But not sure how to do this...

[image]

For blending textures in one rectangle (the first image), I used the following code..

Objective C code...

```
- (void) display {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, targetFBO);

    glUseProgram(program);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureTop);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBot);

    glUniform1i(inputTextureTop, 2);
    glUniform1i(inputTextureBot, 3);

    glUniform1f(alphaTop, alpha);

    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glVertexAttribPointer(position, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, imageVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(inputTextureCoordinate, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Vertex shader...

```
 attribute vec4 position;
 attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

 void main()
 {
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
 }
```

Fragment shader...

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D inputTextureTop;
uniform sampler2D inputTextureBot;

uniform highp float alphaTop;

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 pixelTop = texture2D(inputTextureTop, textureCoordinate);
    lowp vec4 pixelBot = texture2D(inputTextureBot, textureCoordinate);

    gl_FragColor = someBlendOperation(pixelTop, pixelBot);
}
```

Comment: May be I can do some geometric operation in the fragment shader to get the XY of the top pixel.

Comment: Hi i'm having the same problem, @Max solution doesn't seams to deal with the need to draw the top image at a different size and rotation than the background image, how did you managed to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass 2 texture coordinates to shader and modify shader

Add to ObjectiveC

```
glVertexAttribPointer(inputTextureCoordinate2, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates2);
```

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate2;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
    textureCoordinate2 = inputTextureCoordinate2.xy;
}
```

Frag Shader

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;

uniform sampler2D inputTextureTop;
uniform sampler2D inputTextureBot;

uniform highp float alphaTop;

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 pixelTop = texture2D(inputTextureTop, textureCoordinate);
    lowp vec4 pixelBot = texture2D(inputTextureBot, textureCoordinate2);

    gl_FragColor = someBlendOperation(pixelTop, pixelBot);
}
```

BTW inputTextureCoordinate is not necessary to be vec4 but it could be vec2

Comment: Thanks Max! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Max, I have a similar question, could you please help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you posted it somewhere?

Comment: i'm having the same problem, @Max how does your solution deals with the need to draw the top image at a different size and rotation than the background image?

Comment: I advice you to post question and describe everything. You can draw one image on screen and draw second over it or you can blend 2 texture in shader. When you think about shader you should understand that you draw single triangle and full image has many triangles. So first solution might be simpler for you.

Comment: @Max In your answer, I presume there're two triangles forming a rectangle of the size of the larger texture; both textures would be wrapped on this single rectangle only. Now the texture coordinates of the larger texture is trivial, but what would the texture coordinates of the smaller one be? Say in the question, to get the second image as output, what would be the (monkey) texture coordinate of the top-left vertex?

Answer (score 5):

If you're blending two textures on the same primitive, then you can mix the colors in the shader.

However if you want to blend two different primitives, then what you really just want to use is hardware blending (GL_BLEND).

Draw the bottom picture by itself, then enable blending and draw the top picture. The alpha value of the top picture controls how transparent it will be.

You don't really want to try to draw both quads in the same draw call, since they don't use the same coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But using GL_BLEND I can only do a certain number of blending operations. What I really want do is define the blending formula myself (like Photoshop blending modes...multiply, overlay, screen etc). I was thinking if I could do some 2D transformation on the textureCoordinate.xy before passing it to the texture2D(inputTextureTop, textureCoordinate) function, to make it rotate, translate and scale?

Comment: abix I have some opencl code we used to do a reverse transform lookup of source coords for dest pixels here's a gist link https://gist.github.com/victusfate/bdbed266a73a19f81a94