# Edit video frames

Tags: java, android, video-processing

How can I put an image in each frame of a video file and save it with this edition?

I have heard about OpenCV or using Surfaces, but I don't know if this is the easiest way...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is very common and depends on details. So, if you need to do that programmatically, you can:

1. Use FFMPEG [filter](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_filter_howto).
2. Use FFMPEG for decoding video frames and OpenGL ES for presentation. Blend images on presentation [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242443/how-do-i-blend-two-textures-with-different-co-ordinates-in-opengl-es-2-0-on-ipho).
3. Use FFMPEG for decoding and [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) for presentation. The same as prev. one, the only differense you will use java API to blend images.
4. Use [Media API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQws6vsoav8)

1 and 2 are flexible, but you will have a deal with native code. You must be familiar with JNI, NDK. 3 is not good enough and you can get some performance issues. 4 would be the best choice, but I'm not sure that you will find any tutorial or example how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to add a watermark to a video. I have seen some tutorials about how to use ffmpeg in android, but I still not getting the results that I want...