# How to Merge two uniform samplerExternalOES textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera

I am writing an Android Application in which i am able to run two cameras Simultaneously using Surface Texture. My Plan is to once receiving OnFrameAvailable call back for both the camera (i.e SurfaceTextur) merging them as shown in Figure using opengl shader.
[image]

For merging part,i will provide position and window height width to shdaer. Based on that shader will merge one texture with another (like PIP) and return a final texture which i should able to render. How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to design your own vertex shader and fragment shader.

In fragment shader, use `uniform sampler2D` to get the information of textures and do some blending to achieve your goal.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097145/opengl-mask-with-multiple-textures) is an example of doing blending and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242443/how-do-i-blend-two-textures-with-different-co-ordinates-in-opengl-es-2-0-on-ipho) says how to mix the different size images.

Hope it helps.

Comment: uniform sampler2D is for bitmaps. He is asking for two uniform samplerExternalOES.